# Intellisense does not recognize partial class

Tags: c#, blazor, intellisense, partial

I am running a Blazor test project with Blazorized (which is awesome) and everything works fine. However, there is a small, irritating issue and that is that the code behind (.cs) of one of the (2) pages does not recognize that it is a partial class of a razor file
[image]

[image]

So the protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() says there is nothing to override.
Code works fine however, but this is just bugging me. Tried rebuilding several times, quit Visual Studio and reload solution and also deleting the cache

Hope somebody has a clue...

[image]

Comment: Can you you show your class declaration?  (just the declaration, not the body)

Comment: Just did. Visual Studio seems to think that it is not a partial class, as the name and the keyword partial are greyed out

Comment: What version of VS?  I don't have this problemn at all.

Comment: There is something wrong with your version/config/plugins.

Comment: It has to with using a blazorised select component.  When I use this in the 
most basic form, the intellisense of my code behind class shows an error. Where it just works fine .... https://blazorise.com/docs/components/select/

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Blazorise.  It's Blazor / VS.

Comment: I normally would agree with you @Rob, but given this question is about intellisense, it's actually helpful to see how VS is rendering the text.

Comment: @HenkHolterman 16.9.2, and I only have this with the Blazorised select component. Other components don't have this effect. I have replaced the select component with the HTML select and some javascript and it works just fine now.

Comment: I faced the same issue when using Visual Studio. You explicitly inherit from ComponentBase and then remote Component, it will be fine then. I use Rider because of these issues.

Comment: Explicit inherit also does not solve the problem, unfortunately. I think I will just stick to using a HTML <select> instead of the Blazorized <Select>. Just for the *!@@@ intellisense not working

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your .csproj file to see if your partial class is being excluded from compile!

Sometimes Visual studio sometimes borks the csproj file when adding/removing .razor .cs files and you end up with unwanted statements removing your partial class .cs file from the project.

something like...

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Components\SomeComponent.razor.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Happens all the time to me.  Get rid of these unnecessary compile remove lines to get msbuild/intellisense to see your partial class .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

razor file and razor.cs class should have the same namespace. so if you try to change t default namespace in the razor.cs file, it will start giving you this error.

if you don't want to use the default namespace then you can define the same namespace in both files.

you can define the namespace in the razor file like this `@namespace TestNameSpace` on top. and in partial class like `namespace TestNameSpace`.

Typically, a component's namespace is derived from the app's root namespace and the component's location (folder) within the app. If the app's root namespace is BlazorSample and the Counter component resides in the Pages folder:

- The Counter component's namespace is BlazorSample.Pages.
- The fully qualified type name of the component is
  BlazorSample.Pages.Counter.

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#namespaces

Comment: The OP already stated that it compiles fine, which implies the namespace is ok.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it’s unclear from question. Let’s wait for OP to comment.

Comment: It is not the namespace. Tried that.

Comment: @jeroentjeathome is my solution working for you? Have you tried to change the namespace of the partial class? Can you try with the same namespcase in razor and razor.cs class?

Comment: No, does not work. Also, when I use other blazorized components, I don't have this problem. And when I replace the Select component by a custom HTML select, it also does not destroy the intellisense

Comment: @jeroentjeathome shall I delete my answer? What framework are you using?

Comment: @jeroentjeathome are you able to run the application?

Comment: @viveknuna "Code works fine however," so this is not a code problem but rather an Intellisense issue.  I've experience very, very many of them, especially in working with Blazor.  In fact, in the case of EventCallback<T>, I get an error 100% of the time, and it goes away only randomly.