# Blazor component has CS0103 The name when moved or copied in

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I created a Blazor WASM app and the app has gotten so large it has become unstable.  Which is a different story.  So I am trying to convert it to a Blazor server side.  The WASM application does compile and run most of the time.

So I created a server-side and started to copy pages and components to the new project.

I have over 600 errors from components and pages that compile using the WASM side.

I have had a problem when I try to move a page to a sub-directory within the Pages directory.

The worst part is that we are in beta-test production and Blazor is falling apart on me.

Please help.

**JudgesSpecAuto.razor**

```
<MatAutocompleteList Items="@JudgesSpecList.Values" Style="width: 600px; min-width: 600px;"
                     TItem="JudgesSpec" Label="Judges Spec" ShowClearButton="true"
                     FullWidth="true" OnTextChanged="@ValueChange" @bind-Value="JSpecValue"
                     CustomStringSelector="@CustomSel">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%;">
      <div style="flex: 1;text-align:left">@context.ClassType</div>
    </div>

  </ItemTemplate>
</MatAutocompleteList>
```

**JudgesSpecAuto.razor**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using BlazingShows.Client.Services;
using BlazingShowsShared.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;


namespace BlazingShows.Client.Components
{
  public partial class JudgesSpecAuto : ComponentBase
  {
    [Parameter] public SortedList<string, JudgesSpec> JudgesSpecList { get; set; } = new();

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<JudgesSpec> OnChange { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public JudgesSpec JSpecValue { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public string JSpecId { get; set; } = "";
    [Inject] private IJudgesSpecApiService jService { get; set; }

    public void ValueChange(string value)
    {

      JSpecValue = jService.GetJudgesSpecByClassType(value);
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) == false)
        OnChange.InvokeAsync(JSpecValue);
    }

    private string CustomSel(JudgesSpec jSpec)
    {
      if (jSpec is null)
        return null;
      return jSpec.ClassType;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My answer here might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/66939911/6527049

Comment: Vivek, you are a lifesaver!  To recap, the issue was that the namespace didn't match.

Comment: I knew that you have similar Issue